# How to control Seagate external drive power options

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a 3TB Seagate Backup Plus USB 3.0 drive. I want to control the drive power options to have it turn off after a period of time, and have installed the Seagate Dashboard app just to set the power options. The dashboard app is way overkill with too many features and services running. I plan on uninstalling the dashboard app.

Will the drive power setting be retained by the drive on dashboard uninstall?

Do the Windows Control Panel power settings apply to the external drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning on "USB selective suspend"  This will manage the power setting options and I would suspect this is what the segate software is modifying.

Control Panel > Power Options > Change plan setting > Changed advanced power settings > navigate down to and expand USB settings turn off USB selective suspend.

Also make sure you download the latest USB 3.0 driver and firmware for the USB 3.0 controller on your motherboard, going by your system specs your USB 3.0 controller.

Here is an article [USB Selective Suspend](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/archive/2011/05/11/demystifying-usb-selective-suspend.aspx).